# Getting a reference to the class/constructor of an component when using transclusion in Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component in my Angular 5 app which wraps another component, and in the constructor of the wrapping component, I would like to get a reference to the transcluded component. Like this:

```
<wrapper-component>
    <wrapped-component></wrapped-component>
</wrapped-component>
```

In my `wrapper-component` I would like to get a reference to the `wrapped-component`. Actually, all I need is a reference to the constructor, like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'wrapper-component'
    // ...
)}
export class WrapperComponent {
    getWrappedComponent( 
        // can this be done?
    )
}
```

I can think of ways of doing this by passing the `wrapped-component` as in input to the `wrapper-component`, but I'd rather not do this since there are several components that are wrapped like this and I'd rather not have all of that boilerplate in my wrapped components.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you need a reference to the instance of a `wrapped-component` component?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood well the problem, I think you are looking for the **@ContentChild** decorator. With @ContentChild you can get the instance of the content projected inside a component, in this case, your WrapperComponent. 
You can use it like this: (remember that the WrappedComponent ref will be available on **ngAfterContentInit** life hook as shown in example)

```
@Component({
selector: 'wrapper-component'
// ...
)}
export class WrapperComponent {
    @ContentChild(WrappedComponent) wrappedComponent: WrappedComponent
    ngAfterContentInit() {
          // use wrapped component
          this.wrappedComponent. // whatever
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.